# Does CnosDB Support Parallel Query Processing?

Tags: cnosdb

I've got a lot of sensor data and would like to do some aggregate functions. I am thinking whether this could be scaled if I am running for a long period of time, or for multiple fields.

e.g.: I am monitoring many cities' air quality. The station is the tag, while temperature and visibility are the fields. Sample query would be like as follows:

```
> SELECT * FROM air
name: air
time                 pressure station     temperature visibility
----                 -------- -------     ----------- ----------
2021-08-31T16:00:00Z 78       LianYunGang 63          71
2021-08-31T16:00:00Z 75       XiaoMaiDao  79          68
```

The collection interval is microseconds and the retention could be forever.

How can I optimize these queries:
**a query with a very long period of time**

```
SELECT MEAN(temperature) FROM air WHERE time > '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND time < '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'
```

**a query involving multiple fields**

```
SELECT MEAN(temperature) , MEAN(visibility) FROM air WHERE time > '2021-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND time < '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'
```

**a query with a very long period of time**
Could we run the same query but with different segment of period all together on all nodes, then apply the same aggregate function all in once?
**a query involving multiple fields**
Could we run the same query but with each single field during the query processing at the same time on all nodes, then join them all in once?

*These queries could be scaled in the cluster for the sake of better query processing performance.*

Built-in functions such as min, max could be enhanced in the same logic while the product itself could offer some features similar to map reduce.